# Calling static method via Multiple threads - Can they meddle with each other's Input Parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, static-methods, parallel.foreach

My code gets called by AJAX UI (Multiple threads), and post data processing it sends output in Json. Recently while refactoring the code, we have shifted lot of common and repeated methods to a separate file, where we have made the them static, since we are not working on any static / shared data. 
Following is a sample design our static method:

```
public class Helper
{
   public static C Method1(List<A> aList, List<B> bList)
   {
      C objC = new C();

      // Create ObjC based on inputs aList and bList

      return objC;
   }
}
```

Now, my understanding is that the following call will have no issue, when called in a Parallel.foreach or any other multithread scenario, please verify.

```
C resultC = Helper.Method1(aList, bList);
```

However we have doubt, can there be a rare case possible where two threads make the above mentioned call and one thread data of aList, bList, is replaced by another thread, thus giving a flawed result (may be exception), which can for that matter will be impossible to debug and repeat, since two threads have to go / execute together in precise milli seconds that method takes to execute

Please share your view are we on right track to create the above mentioned design or there are pits that we are not able to see. We can easily replace by instance method, they are surely thread safe in this scenario, since each thread has its own instance to work with, but I feel that may not be required and its troublesome to keep creating instance, when we can conveniently work with a static call.

Please note till now I haven't seen an issue with code running, but as I said if this ever happens it will be corner case, for two threads to come at same time and one thread replace the input parameter while other thread is still processing result.

Comment: Every call will have its own thread

Comment: Calling the method shouldn't make a difference, how you use it *may*, if `resultC` is used as a static variable then yes it may happen.

Comment: *Parameters* are not a problem when it comes to multiple threads, *what you pass into those parameters might be*, but there's no way for us to know that from your example. Meaning, if you pass the same list object to two such method calls on different threads, then yes, you will have problems, but not because of the parameters themselves.

Comment: @Sayse No we are not using resultC as static, it is used as an instance output post method call

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen We are having unique dataset for each list, since that come via UI call, so there's no intersection out there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **no**, as long as you pass in different `List` instances across all your different threads. `.NET` handles threading fine, and in itself won't get itself into a tangle, it's only if your code encourages it to do so can things get messy.

The way things get mixed up is by **sharing** state across different threads. So as an example, having a static method you may think it a good idea to use a static variable somewhere:

```
private static int count;

public static void MyMethod() {
   count = count + 1;
   if(count == 5) {
      console.log("Equal to 5");
   }
};
```

This sort of method is **not** thread safe because `count` can be modified by two different threads at the same time. In fact it's possible that `count` could be incremented to 5, and then another thread increment it to 6 before the `if` check, therefore you'd never log anything - which would obviously be a bit confusing.

The other way you can share state, is if you pass something in, hence my caveat at the start of the answer. If you pass the same object into the method from multiple threads this object should ideally be [immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so in your case a collection that can't be modified. This prevents the internals of the method modifying the object that could impact another thread. As already mentioned though, this is only a concern if you pass the same instances in, within different threads.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it does clarify my doubt. I am taking care of the point that different objects are created and passed to the static method. I am not modifying any static data type inside the static method

Answer (score 0):

Method call will not interfere with other method calls from different thread. You have to think carefully only about static variables. Also if you share input parameters aList or bList between threads you can run into troubles.